# Background Color Being Applied To Previous Elements in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, list, overflow

I'm currently working on a pricing table using W3 school example. However, the styling from the div below is being applied to everything above. I want it to apply only to that specific div.

**I've tried using:** overflow: hidden; 
It did not work because the content in the div was hidden but it did remove the background.

**I also tried:** putting the three lists inside a div hoping it would wrap the list around it and would not be affected by the div below. Instead there appeared to be no effect.

**My desired effect:** is to be able to put another div below this list, and apply a background color without it affecting the rest of the page.

Per request, I will insert

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.price {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.price:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.price .header {
    background-color: #111;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.price li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .columns {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Responsive Pricing Tables</h2>
<p style="text-align:center">Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Basic</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 9.99 / year</li>
    <li>10GB Storage</li>
    <li>10 Emails</li>
    <li>10 Domains</li>
    <li>1GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Pro</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 24.99 / year</li>
    <li>25GB Storage</li>
    <li>25 Emails</li>
    <li>25 Domains</li>
    <li>2GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Premium</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 49.99 / year</li>
    <li>50GB Storage</li>
    <li>50 Emails</li>
    <li>50 Domains</li>
    <li>5GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- THIS IS WHERE MORE CONTENT WOULD GO -->
<div style="background-color: black"> <!-- WHY DOES THIS AFFECT EVERYTHING ABOVE IT? -->
 <span style="color: white;">hello</span>
</div>
<!-- END OF FOOTER -->

</body>
</html>
```

[Example of what is happening + code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW56J.png)

Comment: Can you put the code here instead of pic of it?

Comment: @Lucifer I have added the code into the post.

Comment: The problem seems to be with `* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cascaded term in CSS illustrate this :
Priority one : direct defined style in HTML balise
Priority two (lower) : CSS style in the header of the HTML file
Lower priority : CSS style in a separate CSS file

Now, how tho resolve your problem?
It's not a cascading problem (that why you're searching too much time) but you use float:left on your column style.

Then, you've to create a "white" class for your other div (in `<li>` balise)

or you can create a .other class with float: left for the last div in black

Hope, I've help you :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.price {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.price:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.price .header {
    background-color: #111;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.price li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.other {
 float: left;
}
 

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .columns {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Responsive Pricing Tables</h2>
<p style="text-align:center">Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Basic</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 9.99 / year</li>
    <li>10GB Storage</li>
    <li>10 Emails</li>
    <li>10 Domains</li>
    <li>1GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Pro</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 24.99 / year</li>
    <li>25GB Storage</li>
    <li>25 Emails</li>
    <li>25 Domains</li>
    <li>2GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Premium</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 49.99 / year</li>
    <li>50GB Storage</li>
    <li>50 Emails</li>
    <li>50 Domains</li>
    <li>5GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- THIS IS WHERE MORE CONTENT WOULD GO -->
<div class="other" id="other" style="background-color: black"> <!-- WHY DOES THIS AFFECT EVERYTHING ABOVE IT? -->
 test
 <span style="color: white;">hello</span>
</div>
<!-- END OF FOOTER -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This problem was having me scratch my head in confusion. I'm happy it was as simple as just adding the line "float: left;" into my CSS.